# How to add attributes to tags in memory using Ext.js?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How would I pull this off using Ext.js?

```
var html = '<div><a href="a.htm">a</a><a href="b.htm">b</a></div>';

$(html).find('a').attr('target', '_blank'); // the jQuery way
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the first answer is correct, it does it in a really roundabout way:

```
var dom = Ext.DomHelper.createDom({
    html: '<a href="a.htm">a</a><a href="b.htm">b</a>'
});

Ext.get(dom).select('a').set({
    target: '_blank'
});
```

Comment: Ah, `Ext.get`, gotcha.  I was a little surprised when I assumed there was no method chaining way of doing it.  I'm still a little surprised that `createDom` returns an `HTMLElement` though and not an `Ext.element`.

Comment: That would be a nice addition I suppose. A lot of those methods have an option to return either an HTMLElement or an Ext.Element.

Comment: dom actually has a div within a div when you do it that way.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but just selected the inner div out of it.  Your answer, now that you've changed it, no longer answers my question, since `html` isn't something I'm just declaring in the code -- it's a response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ext.JS 4.1,

```
// createDom makes the passed 'html' a childNode 
// of a new <div id="ext-gen####"></div> element
var htmlEl = Ext.DomHelper.createDom({html: '<div><a href="a.htm">a</a><a href="b.htm">b</a></div>' }),
    memoryDom = Ext.get(htmlEl);

memoryDom.select('a').set({ target: '_blank' });

// removes the <div id="ext-gen####"></div> wrapper
console.log(memoryDom.getHTML());
```